# Objectify Unit Tests are persisting data to Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a Unit Test that attempts to follow the Unit Test instructions found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting). I find that any entities that I persist are actually stored in the "real" Google Cloud Platform DataStore associated with my Google Project.

My intention was that the Entities would be persisted to In Memory storage and torn down after each test.

When the test runs it appears that it tries to write to the Local Datastore, but everything somehow ends up being written to the Cloud Datastore. Here's the console output

> com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
>   INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
>       Type: High Replication
>       Storage: In-memory
>   Jan 09, 2019 10:44:49 AM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
>   INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
>       Type: High Replication
>       Storage: In-memory

Here's my Unit Test

```
public class AccountGCPDatastoreDaoTest {

private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
            new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy());

private Closeable session;

private AccountGCPDatastoreDao dao = new AccountGCPDatastoreDao();

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
    System.out.println("init Objectify");
    ObjectifyService.init(new ObjectifyFactory());
    ObjectifyService.register(Account.class);
}

@Before
public void setUp() { ;
    helper.setUp();
    session = ObjectifyService.begin();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    session.close();
    helper.tearDown();
}


@Test
public void save() {
    Account account = new Account(1L, "Test Account", false, AccountType.SMALL);
    dao.save(account);

    Account retAcc = ofy().load().type(Account.class).id(1).now();
    assertEquals(new Long(1),retAcc.getId());
    assertEquals("Test Account",retAcc.getName());
    assertFalse(retAcc.getPaidSubscription());
    assertEquals(AccountType.SMALL,retAcc.getAccountType());
}


@Test
public void findAccountsForRegistration_NoAccountsExist() {

    List<Account> accountsForRegistration = dao.findAccountsForRegistration();
    assertEquals(0,accountsForRegistration.size());


}
```

My Account entity :

```
@Entity
public class Account {

@Id private Long id;
private String name;
private boolean paidSubscription;
@Index private AccountType accountType;

private Account(){}

public Account(Long id,
               String name,
               boolean paidSubscription,
               AccountType accountType){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.paidSubscription = paidSubscription;
    this.accountType = accountType;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public AccountType getAccountType(){
    return accountType;
}

public boolean getPaidSubscription() {
    return paidSubscription;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Objectify6, which uses the new dedicated datastore API, but you're looking at documentation for the old appengine-everything-combined API.

The new datastore API has a completely different emulator. That local test harness you're using is what you would use with Objectify5 or what used to be called the "appengine datastore low level API".

The documentation for setting up a test environment for the new API wasn't great the last time I looked. I recommend looking at Objectify's test harness itself. You can actually use the Objectify JUnit5 interceptors directly if you want to upgrade from JUnit4. Otherwise it shouldn't be too hard to figure out what's going on.

Here's the meat of it:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/util/LocalDatastoreExtension.java
https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/util/ObjectifyExtension.java

Comment: thanks @stickfigure - that's exactly what I was doing. I moved to JUnit 5 ( not as easy as I might have hoped ) and have implemented the JUnit5 interceptors you suggest. The situation is much better, but I now get a timeout memcached tries to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211 - it recovers and runs the tests, but have you any ideas how to get rid of that annoyance?

Comment: I just run memcached locally. But you can construct ObjectifyFactory without memcached; it disables the cache, which is probably fine for your tests.

Comment: Now 4y later and this is still the best answer?  For the life of me, I can't find _any_ documentation about how to do this other that copying these classes and figuring out how to make them work.  I'd expect this to be a very common test-case.

Comment: Not sure what's going on.  I've created similar classes locally and used `@ExtendWith` on my test base class to get them operational; the debugger shows everything being called.  The `LocalDatastoreHelper` is being started but the `helper.reset()` call fails with "Connection refused: connect".  Perhaps because I removed the Memcache code?

Comment: Ah...  I needed a `setPort(...)` call when creating the LocalDatastoreHelper.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of @stickfigure's answer.  It's Kotlin but should be easy enough to regress into Java if that's your language of choice.

**LocalDatastoreExtension.kt:**

```
package com.mydomain.common

import com.google.cloud.datastore.testing.LocalDatastoreHelper
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext


/**
 * Sets up and tears down the Local Datastore emulator
 */
class LocalDatastoreExtension : BeforeAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext) {
        if (getHelper(context) == null) {
            val helper = LocalDatastoreHelper.newBuilder()
                .setPort(DATASTORE_PORT)
                .setConsistency(1.0) // we always have strong consistency now
                .setStoreOnDisk(false)
                .build()
            context.root.getStore(ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL).put(LocalDatastoreHelper::class.java, helper)
            helper.start()
        }
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        val helper = getHelper(context)
        helper!!.reset()
    }

    companion object {
        const val DATASTORE_PORT = 8585

        /* Get the helper created in beforeAll; it should be global so there will one per test run  */
        fun getHelper(context: ExtensionContext): LocalDatastoreHelper? {
            return context.root.getStore(ExtensionContext.Namespace.GLOBAL).get<LocalDatastoreHelper>(
                LocalDatastoreHelper::class.java,
                LocalDatastoreHelper::class.java
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ObjectifyExtension.kt:**

```
package com.mydomain.common

import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService
import com.googlecode.objectify.util.Closeable
import com.mydomain.common.LocalDatastoreExtension
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterEachCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext


/**
 * Sets up and tears down the Objectify local unit test harness environment
 */
class ObjectifyExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        val helper = LocalDatastoreExtension.getHelper(context)
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(
            helper,
            "This extension depends on " + LocalDatastoreExtension::class.java.simpleName
        )
        val datastore: Datastore = helper!!.options.service
        ObjectifyService.init(ObjectifyFactory(datastore))
        /* GlobalInit.registerObjectifyClasses() */
        val rootService: Closeable = ObjectifyService.begin()
        context.getStore(NAMESPACE).put(Closeable::class.java, rootService)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        val rootService: Closeable = context.getStore(NAMESPACE).get(
            Closeable::class.java,
            Closeable::class.java
        )
        rootService.close()
    }

    companion object {
        private val NAMESPACE = ExtensionContext.Namespace.create(ObjectifyExtension::class.java)
    }
}
```

**MyClassTest.kt:**

```
package com.mydomain.common

import kotlin.test.*

import com.mydomain.common.LocalDatastoreExtension
import com.mydomain.common.ObjectifyExtension
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith

@ExtendWith(
    LocalDatastoreExtension::class,
    ObjectifyExtension::class,
)
class MyClassTest {
    @BeforeTest
    fun setup() {
        // This is here to ensure we're not somehow accessing the production database.
        assertFalse(MyClass.getAll().hasNext())
    }

    @Test
    fun testSomething() {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: "Regress into Java" - how dare you!!

Comment: Hah!  I wondered if that would get a rise out of anybody.  :-)  I used the term merely because I started in Java and converted the underlying code to Kotlin some months back.  And because it was fun.